# Access Models from console in play framework

Tags: playframework

How to access models from console in Play Framework?

I get this error when trying to fetch a user.

```
scala> import models._
import models._

scala> User.find.byId(1)
java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When entering the console there is no application running, so there is no connection pool kept for the database, etc.

You can use a `StaticApplication` to solve this.

```
scala> import play.core.StaticApplication
scala> import java.io.File
scala> val app = new StaticApplication(new File("."))
```

Creating the `StaticApplication` will automatically start it. And when you're done:

```
scala> play.api.Play.stop
```

Comment: `val app = new play.core.StaticApplication(new java.io.File("."))` , in short.