# Calling into Play framework app from the Scala console

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a Play Framework 2.3 app. I can drop into a Scala console with `activator console`. However, when I try to call into code from my app, specifically some helper function which uses `WS`, which uses the implicit `import play.api.Play.current` to retrieve the currently running app, I get the error message `java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application`.

What steps do I have to take to be able to load my app into the current console session?

There is [a similar existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194695/play-2-0-access-running-fakeapplication-from-scala-console), but the accepted answer appears to be using a mock app from the framework's test helpers. Preferably, I would like to run in the context of my actual app. If I must use a fake app, would it be possible to make it match my development environment (what I get when running `activator run`) rather than my test environment (what I get when running the unit tests)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the goal of running in such way?

Comment: @cchantep It's nice to be able to play with things in the REPL.

Comment: Similarly, you can use `StaticApplication` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435415/access-models-from-console-in-play-framework  This question essentially asks the same thing, except for models that require the database. The common ground is that they both require the implicit app.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224187/play-2-4-console-not-working-as-documented

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this specific case you can just create an Application instance and use it instead of the implicit one:

```
// Tested in 2.3.7
import play.api.{Play, Mode, DefaultApplication}
import java.io.File
import play.api.libs.ws.WS

val application = new DefaultApplication(
    new File("."),
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
    None,
    Mode.Dev
)

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

WS.client(application).url("http://www.google.com").get().map((x) => println(x.body))
```

Comment: Tks for this. I needed an additional `Play.start(application)` to get going

Answer (score 8):

For future readers, for Play framework 2.5.x:

```
import play.api._
val env = Environment(new java.io.File("."), this.getClass.getClassLoader, Mode.Dev)
val context = ApplicationLoader.createContext(env)
val loader = ApplicationLoader(context)
val app = loader.load(context)
Play.start(app)
```

Source:  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlayConsole#Launch-the-interactive-console